# All critical git commands are hanging despite running gc and prune

Tags: git

On my windows 10 machine via cmder terminal, every single important git command is now hanging completely. I haven't waited more than 5 minutes to cancel.

For example, git pull will just hang indefinitely. I will then press ctrl+c, and when I run git status (no problem with this) I'll see files being updated. However, no commit is shown in the git log.

git checkout is also hanging, nothing is happening.

I have no idea how to fix this. I have run git prune, git gc, and git fsck --unreachable. Nothing showed up when I ran git fsck --unreachable or git fsck at all, and when I ran git prune it just completed but fixed nothing. Git gc also completed but fixed nothing.

EDIT: ran `strace git checkout <branch>`

```
λ strace git checkout develop
--- Process 28092 created
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll at 00007ffa2c0b0000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll at 00007ffa29710000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll at 00007ffa28a10000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll at 00007ffa29670000
--- Process 28092 thread 16828 created
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll at 00007ffa29dc0000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll at 00007ffa29290000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll at 00007ffa29190000
--- Process 28092 thread 25116 created
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll at 00007ffa2b5c0000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll at 00007ffa29a70000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll at 00007ffa292e0000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll at 00007ffa281a0000
--- Process 28092 thread 19616 created
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll at 00007ffa28220000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll at 00007ffa28970000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll at 00007ffa2b380000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll at 00007ffa29c80000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll at 00007ffa28130000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll at 00007ffa280b0000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll at 00007ffa29ba0000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll at 00007ffa29a30000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll at 00007ffa28f70000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll at 00007ffa2b420000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll at 00007ffa29170000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll at 00007ffa28110000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll at 00007ffa28180000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll at 00007ffa29a00000
--- Process 28092 loaded C:\Users\dontdoxpls\Desktop\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\ConEmuHk64.dll at 00007e1100000000
--- Process 25040 created
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll at 00007ffa2c0b0000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll at 00007ffa29710000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll at 00007ffa28a10000
--- Process 25040 thread 28028 created
--- Process 25040 thread 9448 created
--- Process 25040 thread 26428 created
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll at 00007ffa29c80000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Users\dontdoxpls\Desktop\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\mingw64\bin\libintl-8.dll at 0000000061cc0000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Users\dontdoxpls\Desktop\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\mingw64\bin\libiconv-2.dll at 0000000066000000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll at 00007ffa29670000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Users\dontdoxpls\Desktop\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\mingw64\bin\libpcre-1.dll at 0000000069140000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll at 0000000001a20000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll at 00007ffa2b380000
--- Process 25040 unloaded DLL at 0000000001a20000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Users\dontdoxpls\Desktop\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\mingw64\bin\zlib1.dll at 0000000062e80000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll at 00007ffa29a70000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll at 00007ffa2b420000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll at 00007ffa29170000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll at 00007ffa29a30000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll at 00007ffa28f70000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll at 00007ffa28970000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll at 00007ffa29190000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll at 00007ffa2b310000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Users\dontdoxpls\Desktop\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\mingw64\bin\libssp-0.dll at 0000000068ac0000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll at 00007ffa29a00000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll at 00007ffa28180000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll at 00007ffa27250000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll at 00007ffa28e90000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll at 00007ffa27b10000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll at 00007ffa281a0000
--- Process 25040 loaded C:\Users\dontdoxpls\Desktop\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\ConEmuHk64.dll at 00007e1100000000
--- Process 25040 thread 25204 created
--- Process 25040 thread 21648 created
--- Process 25040 thread 16420 created
--- Process 25040 thread 28384 created
--- Process 25040 thread 21212 created
--- Process 25040 thread 8304 created
--- Process 25040 thread 5732 created
--- Process 25040 thread 19088 created
--- Process 25040 thread 15156 created
--- Process 25040 thread 29212 created
--- Process 25040 thread 29892 created
--- Process 25040 thread 28188 created
--- Process 25040 thread 28292 created
--- Process 25040 thread 20504 created
--- Process 25040 thread 1768 created
--- Process 25040 thread 14520 created
--- Process 25040 thread 16080 created
--- Process 25040 thread 24820 created
--- Process 25040 thread 28384 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 1768 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 28292 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 20504 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 16080 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 14520 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 15156 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 24820 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 8304 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 21648 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 28188 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 19088 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 21212 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 29892 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 5732 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 29212 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 16420 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 25040 thread 19684 created
```

this isn't the full output. While I was editing this question some threads exited. so it's hanging on the thread creation?

EDIT: This definitely is not a cmder issue either. I just ran git bash and am running into the same issue. I did `GIT_TRACE=1 git checkout <branch>` and it produced nothing, only this

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git checkout develop
20:31:33.554953 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
20:31:33.559955 git.c:419               trace: built-in: git checkout develop
```

EDIT: **The issue was resolved** by restarting my computer. I am not sure why that fixed it or what caused the issue in the first place. Hopefully someone will find an explanation.

Comment: Git has verbose options, have you tried them?

Comment: yeah, checkout doesn't have a verbose option

Comment: `strace` always exists (on Linux; on MacOS or Solaris, see `dtruss`); to track syscalls on Linux with less overhead, see also [sysdig](https://sysdig.com/). Watching the actual filesystem or network operations will let you know what's hanging.

Comment: ran it for git checkout, please see output above

Comment: Use the `-f` argument to `strace` to follow actions done in subprocesses. Though on Windows you may need a different set of tools built for the platform; strace proper is very Linux-specific -- I'm astonished Cygwin (or whatever you're using) provides the command at all.

Comment: So I restarted my computer and it seems to be working fine now. However I think there still needs to be an explanation for this random behavior.

Comment: @JeremyFisher: File locking. You restarted the computer and the problem went away. You will never get a good explanation now.

Comment: I don't think file locking is the answer because I closed my editor and I still had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by restarting my PC. I am not sure why that fixed it or what caused the problem in the first place. Hopefully someone will find a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to execute the same commands, still in CmdEr (but also, for testing in a regular CMD) *after* having set a simplified PATH:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

See if the issue persists then.