# Is there a workaround to make Robohelp 2019 work with Windows 10 ssh-agent?

Tags: git, ssh, windows-10, adobe, robohelp

I am new to Robohelp. One of the announced feature of the current new Robohelp 2019 release (NOT Robohelp Classic 2019) is using GIT for source control.

In Adobe Robohelp manual is requirement to have installed Git for Windows with Unix tools included. That means that the PATH environment variable gets this record:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
```

which has to be propagated inside PATH to be listed sooner than:

```
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
```

where the Windows 10 SSH tools reside.

This is - at least I think - to make possible to call the ssh tools like ssh-agent from the command line, which is not possible when you install Git for Windows only with basic support of command line tools.

I can't install Git for Windows with the unix tools, since it messes up some other programs like windows find etc. (there is even a warning during Git for Windows installation this will happen)so I am trying to run Robohelp with Windows 10 open ssh tools.

So far I am not successful. When I fill in the Robohelp Git profile form my private ssh key (id_rsa), the Robohelp throws me an error:

> SSH Key could not be added to the ssh-agent.
>   Make sure that ssh-agent is running and the key is valid

The ssh-agent is running that time and the key is also valid. I have checked it multiple times. I have even once installed Git for WIndwos with unix tools and successfully connect to git repo via ssh in Robohlep. But when I install Git for WIndows without the tools and try to connect using W10 ssh tools the above error is still thrown.

I have also tried to make Git for Windows work together with w10 ssh - via the GIT_SSH_COMMAND variable- there is no problem in it.

But in Robohelp no luck yet and I guess that Robohelp is not using git at all when checking the added private key, since otherwise only Git for Windows with minimum command line support would be enough.

Is there some workaround to make Robhelp 2019 properly work with Windwos 10 ssh tools without the need to install Git for Windows with Unix tools support ? Does anyone know what exactly Robohelp is calling when checking the SSH private key ?

RESOLUTION

The answer of VonC below turned out to be most probably the only solution for this issue. Based on that answer I have created .bat file with following content

```
@echo off
set SSH_HOME="C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\"
set Path=%SSH_HOME%;%Path%
start "" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe RoboHelp 2019\RoboHelp.exe"
```

That way the RoboHelp has what it needs and I don't mess anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't install Git for Windows with the unix tools, since it messes up some other programs like windows find etc

Yes, you can: Select the portable version of the [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (currently [`PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.21.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.21.0-64-bit.7z.exe)) and extract that archive anywhere you want: that will not mess with your current setup.

Then launch your tool from a CMD whare you have set a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55887169/6309):

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

That PATH will be valid only in that CMD, and won't interfere with your other tools.
It will allow your program to run with Git bash executables and commands first.